# Is it possible to add bookmark to pdf outputs

Tags: r

If I have a 6 pages pdf file, and I would like to add bookmark to it. Is it possible to add that using R?

The bookmark outline is looks like this:

[image]

The output will looks like following: (3 => Top, 3.1 => Second)

[image]

Anyway we can achieve this goal?

While I search for answers, I did come across this: https://www.dept.psu.edu/statgen/software/harupdf/help/addoutline.html
But it seems like this package is no longer supported. Any other package or method? Would prefer use R , instead of python.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a bookmarks file like this:

```
0 "Part 1" 1 open
1 "Part 1A" 2
1 "Part 1B" 3
0 "Part 2" 4
1 "Part 2a" 5
```

And then use `cpdf -add-bookmarks bookmarks.txt in.pdf -o out.pdf`. The first column is the indentation level, then the text, then the page number, then optionally "open" to show that the bookmark is open.

Comment: Is it possible to give a example on how to setup and add to existing file in details? Do you mean to create a txt file first? if my pdf output is `test.pdf`. What should I do?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you prepare `bookmarks.txt` as you like, from whichever programming language you are using. Then call out to `cpdf`.